# Field with type data Array always return nil on conditional validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have model Campaign with fields :

```
class Campaign
   field :title, type: String
   field :start_date, type: Date
   field :end_date, type: Date
   field :locations, type: Array, default: []
   field :is_deleted, type: Boolean, default: false
   field :disabled, type: Boolean, default: false

   validate: :conflict_date, if: :check_location

   belongs_to :native_ad

   private

   def check_location
      locations.include?('Location 1') || locations.include?('Location 2')
   end

   def conflict_date
       ## another condition
   end
end
```

In create & update record action is working and value of `locations` is exists on `check_location` method but, when updating single attribute like :

```
def destroy
    @campaign = Campaign.find(params[:id])
    @campaign.update_attributes(is_deleted: true)
    ## other stuff
end
```

`locations` always return `nil`

debugger on `check_location` method :

```
[1] pry(#<Campaign>)> locations
=> nil
[2] pry(#<Campaign>)> self
=> #<Campaign _id: 58ca3fa7fe37a86982000000, created_at: 2017-03-16 07:32:59 UTC, updated_at: 2017-03-16 07:32:59 UTC, start_date: 2017-03-16 00:00:00 UTC, end_date: 2018-03-16 00:00:00 UTC, locations: nil, disabled: false, is_deleted: true, native_ad_id: BSON::ObjectId('58ca3b52fe37a86590000000')>
[3] pry(#<Campaign>)> end_date
=> Fri, 16 Mar 2018
[4] pry(#<Campaign>)> start_date
=> Thu, 16 Mar 2017
```

note : value of locations is exist in database

create action

```
def create
   @campaign = Campaign.new(campaign_params)
   if @campaign.save
      redirect_to campaigns_path
   else
      render :new      
   end
end

private

def campaign_params
   params.require(:campaign).permit(:start_date, :end_date, :native_ad, locations: [])
end
```

I'm use :

- Rails. 4.2.4
- Mongoid 5.0.0

Comment: How do you add location to campaign? Can you post you campaign create code?

Comment: @GokulM sure, question updated.

Comment: Why are you doing `update_attributes` on `Campaign` class? Instead it should be called on an instance of `Campaign`.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh sorry my mistake to explain, I have update `destroy` action.

Comment: It looks like `locations` were not saved to the database in first place. Can you fetch the same record in `rails console` and see if `locations` array has something in it?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I have write a note in my question `note : value of locations is exists in database` also when run `self.reload` in debugger `locations` is exists.